# Duda sobre script con javascript

Tags: javascript, web, script

estoy aprendiendo a hacer scripts/extensiones webs con Javascript y en este caso estoy intentando automatizar el clickeo a un boton que produce una barra de carga de 2 minutos y medio y vuelve a aparecer el botón y se vuelve a clickear.

La duda esta en que cuando se termina de llenar la barra, como que la pagina necesita que el usuario este en esa misma pestaña para que vuelva a aparecer el botón y se vuelva a realizar la acción. Es decir, si el usuario tiene dos pestañas abiertas y una es la pagina haciendo esa tarea que ya les comente y la otra es donde esta el usuario navegando, la primera no completa la tarea porque necesita que el usuario cambie de pestaña para volver a empezar el ciclo.

Entonces, mi duda es si existe alguna función de JS que me permita hacer que la pagina interprete que el usuario esta en la pestaña donde se esta ejecutando ella, que no sea un reload.

Desde ya, muchísimas gracias.

Comment: eso solo depende del navegador no del script ya que el navegador suele bloquear la ejecucion cuando se cambia de pestaña, pero eso es dependiendo del navegador, por ejemplo las ejecuciones que dependan de un click se bloquean, pero las que no dependen de objetos del DOM siguen correindo por ejemplo, llamadas ajax